# What is meant by "size-prefixed blob readiness bit is set to NOT_COMPLETE" in ChronicleMap?

Tags: java, chronicle-map

I have a persisted chronicle map with about 160K entries and I am invoking the map with `createOrRecoverPersistedTo(file, true)` where `true` indicates that the map is from the *sameLibraryVersion*.

It is taking long time to build the map and after that it is throwing the following error:

```
size-prefixed blob readiness bit is set to NOT_COMPLETE
```

What does this mean? Can I recover the data from the map. If so how?

**Update**

After sometime, I got this following error (upon re-executing the program)

```
[ERROR] 2019-09-03 14:59:58.413 [main] ChronicleMap - Wrong number of entries counter for tier with index 9, stored: 1213, should be: 1212
[ERROR] 2019-09-03 14:59:58.413 [main] ChronicleMap - wrong lowest free chunk for tier with index 9, stored: 10917, should be: 7281
[ERROR] 2019-09-03 14:59:58.460 [main] ChronicleMap - Wrong number of entries counter for tier with index 23, stored: 1248, should be: 1247
[ERROR] 2019-09-03 14:59:58.460 [main] ChronicleMap - wrong lowest free chunk for tier with index 23, stored: 11232, should be: 7902
[ERROR] 2019-09-03 14:59:58.491 [main] ChronicleMap - Wrong number of entries counter for tier with index 31, stored: 1264, should be: 1263
[ERROR] 2019-09-03 14:59:58.491 [main] ChronicleMap - wrong lowest free chunk for tier with index 31, stored: 11360, should be: 11178
[ERROR] 2019-09-03 14:59:58.522 [main] ChronicleMap - Wrong number of entries counter for tier with index 44, stored: 1201, should be: 1200
[ERROR] 2019-09-03 14:59:58.522 [main] ChronicleMap - wrong lowest free chunk for tier with index 44, stored: 10801, should be: 6147
```

and the map is created. However, I would like to confirm, if there is a chance anytime to get malformed or invalid data due to such an error?

For example, an invalid key or invalid value or a different value for a key or something like this?